# Filtering DVWP from another list

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-designer

I am trying to find a way to filter a DVWP from values on another list.

Both lists are going to be inside an iframe and the first list (Orders) is filtered using querystring, everything works great and it returns multiple values no problem.

The problems is filtering the second list (Invoices). It is actually a SQL datasource for invoices, there can be multiple invoices per order.

I tried using a connection to get filter values and this works but will only use the first row from the Orders list.

IE:
Order list has 3 orders: 123, 456, 789

Invoice list will only show invoices for order 123, and will ignore the others, I am trying to show all invoices related to any order number in the list

I cannot seem to find a way to make it look through all the rows on the order list and use those as filters, is there any way to use each row to filter the other list?

Answer (score 1):

You could open the 2nd web part in SharePoint designer and add a new Parameter to the web part (leave defaults to None as the source of value) and using the Filter button on the ribbon in SPD create a new Filter condition to have "CONTAINS" and for the value use the newly created Parameter. Then set up the connection back in the page but instead of setting up the connection to "Send Filter values" use "Send Parameters" and you shall have the option to choose the name of the new parameters as well as the field to map to.

No actual need for the iFrame, etc.

Comment: I have tried also using the send parameters option but it still only returns matching values for the first item in the order list... ignoring the iframe stuff its basically a webpart page with 2 DVWP, trying to use the order list to match any order number to the invoice list.

filtering seems to only use the first item in the list rather then looping through and using every row

Comment: q: do you have by any chance a Multi-choice valued column? 'Cause that wouldn't work with OOTB Filters.

Comment: no multi choices, i guess im really looking for a way to filter based off multiple values though, instead of just filtering based off one value in the first list I want to use all values

Comment: it is the same issue with multi-valued columns though; as OOTB filters are incapable. I believe Tony Stegeman had a web part enabling such filtering

Answer (score 1):

I would probably switch to a single DVWP with an AggregateDataSource. By doing this, you can filter for each order in turn. This will require you to write your own XSL, however.